# Delphi TWebBrowser identify button enabled

Tags: ajax, delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

The website uses Ajax and the button enables only after the selection of two combobox.

How to identity if the site button is enabled or disabled?

cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the browser's DOM interfaces to access the button element.  Once the page has been loaded, you can query the `TWebBrowser.Document` property for the [`IHTMLDocument2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574.aspx) interface, drill down to the desired button element, query it for the [`IHTMLElement3`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703950.aspx) or [`IHTMLButtonElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704276.aspx) interface, and then read its `disabled` property.

Comment: I'm trying to make a generic function for this task, which would serve to further research.